# how to get the @layout functionality of laravel working?

Tags: layout, view, laravel, laravel-blade

i am new to laravel an trying to learn BLADE but there is a issue which is striking me.
i have an

```
index.blade.php

@layout('master')
```

and i also have a

```
master.blade.php
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Laravel: A Framework For Web Artisans</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

</head>
<body>
hi from body
</body>
</html>
```

the problem is that when ever i try to call the index.blade.php it gives me a
error saying

```
Unhandled Exception
Message:

View [master] doesn't exist.

Location:

C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php on line 170

Stack Trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(107): Laravel\View->path('master')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(218): Laravel\View-                                >__construct('master', Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\helpers.php(526): Laravel\View::make('master', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(386) : eval()'d code(2): view('master')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(386): eval()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\blade.php(71): Laravel\View->get()
#6 [internal function]: Laravel\Blade::Laravel\{closure}(Object(Laravel\View))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\event.php(199): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\event.php(138): Laravel\Event::fire('laravel.view.en...', Array, true)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(348): Laravel\Event::until('laravel.view.en...', Array)
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\view.php(590): Laravel\View->render()
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\response.php(268): Laravel\View->__toString()
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\laravel\laravel.php(180): Laravel\Response->render()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-laravel2\public\index.php(34): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...')
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Please post the controller code too.

Comment: @dhpratik, I'm having the same issue. Did you manage to solve this? How did you do it?
--edit--
I found out that NetBeans didn't add ".php" extension to the file I created!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. It may be an error on your part, or may be down to your environment. Either way, try these three things:

- Put `@layout('master')` right at the top of your php file - no white
  space.
- Make sure your master view is labelled master.blade.php - no
  capitals.
- Make sure master.blade.php is in application/views

Note: If you have your master view in a different folder e.g. application/views/some_folder the correct way to call it is `@layout('some_folder.master')`

Comment: ***Important:** The @layout call must always be on the very first line of the file, with no leading whitespaces or newline breaks.* (from [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#blade-layouts))

Comment: well i have done it as said by you but it then also it gives taht same error.

Comment: where is master.blade.php saved? It should be in application/views

Comment: there is your problem then. If its in home you would have to put @layout('home.master'). For @layout('master') to work, it would need to be directly in the /views directory

Answer (score 0):

Use 
@extends('master') instead of @layout('master')